# Firefox 26 unable to load some websites?

Tags: 13.10, firefox

When using the new version of firefox(26), some websites can not load like in the last version I was using (23). This specific problem happens only in my Ubuntu box.

I have a Windows box with the same firefox version, and everything is just fine. The problem for me is in the design, css and ajax functions does not load properly, some flash websites are the same, some interfaces functionaly just does not work as expected. Trying those sites with the same firefox version in another Linux distro or Windows works perfectly.

What could it be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated my firefox from version 26.0 to version 28.0 and now everything is working normal. I conclude that firefox 26.0 is a bug version for linux OS.